# How do I sort the elements of this NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've the following array containing other arrays.

```
NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nickname1", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil],
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nickname2", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], nil],
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nickname3", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil],
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nickname4", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil],
nil ];
```

How do I sort the elements of this array by the second parameter (the boolean one). can I use NSSortDescriptor ? (I want all YES before).

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method for this.  Since you want the `YES` values (a constant of value 1) sorted before the `NO` values (a constant value of 0), just reverse the order of the objects in the `compare:` call.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSArray *ary1 = (NSArray *)o1;
    NSArray *ary2 = (NSArray *)o2;

    return [[ary2 objectAtIndex:1] compare:[ary1 objectAtIndex:1]];
}];
```